# JAVA setReferenceNull method in class

Tags: java, reference

I'm running out of ideas how to implement void disconnect method in Connection class to put this in a simple way: There is a class Connection which creates up to x(defined by variable) Connection instances using changed Singleton design pattern in another class ConnectionManagment it looks like this:

```
Connection[] connections = {
    Connection.createConnection(),
    Connection.createConnection()
};
```

Then in main I'm using connect() method to get the reference from connections eg:

```
Connection c1 = ConnectionManagment.connect();
```

And now the question part comes how do I create a void setReferenceNull() method
in Connection class since everything is passed by value in Java, I know it's possible to archieve this with method like:

```
public Connection disconnect()
{
    return null;
}
```

And using it like this:

```
c1 = c1.disconnect();
```

But it just looks like crap in my opinion whereas

```
c1.disconnect();
```

Looks just that much better, I'm pretty new to programming in Java but I'm getting a hang of it thanks for help!

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is somehow flawed.

If `disconnect()` does in fact have an empty body, what is the point of having that method in the first place?! You see: code communicates intent. Your code ... communicates confusion, at leat to me.

And if `disconnect()` does some real "tear down" of your connection, then you would be tearing down an element in your initial `connections` array. So **other** clients could no longer use that connections. What is the purpose of your *manager* then, and collecting connections in that "array pool"? As soon as you make a reference to an array member "public", any client is free to `disconnect`. What about other clients then?

So either way, your logic seems broken.

My suggestion: if there is real tear-down required, then consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Otherwise, just forget the part about "disconnecting". Remove the method from your interface, and forget about clients invoking a NOOP (empty) method for no reason.

Comment: My intention was to create 4 static connections, but yeah the other idea would be to exchange the instances in the connections table and put a function that checks if there is an instance with this exact reference if yes then it would let it connect otherwise just return "Connection invalid" is that what you meant?

Comment: I guess we have to stay back: what kind of connections are we talking about? Can they be closed, re-opened? How expensive is establishing a new connection? What did you intend with "pooling" here?

Comment: This was just an exercise class but let's bring a real life example imagine a SSH connection app (also if there was no garbage collector), the server is capable of serving 10 people at once: connections tab length is 10, 10 people connected and 1 is trying to connect(he's our guy A) obviously getting null object, now 1 guy is disconnecting(he's our guy B) from the server and frees the 1 connection the guy that tried before is now able to connect so he does but   now guy A and B have 2 connection objects with the same reference when both tried to connect there's a collision

Comment: Also note we're talking about a static 10 connections(10 different references) I know the collision can be avoided by exchanging the objects and checking if they are valid

Comment: Well, you have to differentiate what you are doing. Some connections can't be shared. You wouldn't want to share ssh connections. One user, one connection. You create one for the user, and you close when he is done. That is what I said: either you have real polling (like in a thread pool), but then you don't close things, or you have closable resources, then you cant pool them.

Comment: So the approach with new user =  new connection in connections, completed connection dropping the connection from connections is one of the better ways to go?

Comment: It feels like. But as said: that really depends on the exact use case. Things that are expensive to create and that can be re-used, you want to reuse. Other things, it is much cleaner to create, use, abandon them. I hope that is good enough for accepting then ... we shouldnt go forth and back with comments like this ;)